# Is destructor invoked when the function call quits and the function generated class instances in heap?

Tags: c++, class, oop

On the main program:

```
void onStack()
{
    Collage colA(24);
    Collage colB(12);
}
```

And Collage constructor/destructor:

```
Collage::Collage(size_tnumPics)
{
    pics = new PNG[numPics];
}

Collage::~Collage()
{
    delete[] pics;
}
```

Assume that PNG class is defined appropriately.

When onStack() function is invoked, would destructor of Collage class be invoked when onStack() quits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question title and example given don't exactly match.

Your function allocates class instances `colA` and `colB` on the **stack**.

After that allocation, `Collage`'s constructor is called, which allocates `png` on the **heap**.

When the function `onStack()` terminates, it calls `Collage`'s destructor, since `colA` and `colB` have gone out of scope. That destructor in turn frees `png` from the heap.

Finally, `onStack`'s stack frame, which includes the memory for `colA` and `colB`, is freed.

So everything allocated in your example will be correctly freed.